# how to access multiple values using getStorageAt?

Tags: addresses, get-storage-at

I have a small smart contract that has 2 functions, one to set 3 numbers and another function returning these 3 numbers.

```
return(a,b,c)

samplecont.setnumbers(100,250,250)
samplecont.getnumbers()
                 [100,250,250]
samplecont.setnumbers(101,260,260)
                 [101,260,260]
samplecont.setnumbers(102,270,270)
                 [102,270,270]
```

I am trying to access the past values of these 3 variables using `getStorageAt`. Have written following code after reading other responses on this topic:
`mycontractaddress` consists of the address if mined contract.

---

```
uint maxBlocks = 50;
uint startBlock = eth.blockNumber;
for (var i = 0; i < maxBlocks; i++) { 
        current = web3.eth.getStorageAt(mycontractaddress, 0, startBlock-i);

        blockDate = new Date(web3.eth.getBlock(startBlock-i).timestamp*1000);

        console.log("Block #" + (startBlock-i) + " Timestamp:" + blockDate.toString()
          +  " Value:" + web3.toDecimal(current));

    }
```

---

however, output only shows the first of the 3 numbers:

```
Block #7547 Timestamp:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:06:55 IST Value:102
Block #7546 Timestamp:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:06:50 IST Value:102
Block #7545 Timestamp:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:06:47 IST Value:102
Block #7544 Timestamp:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:06:45 IST Value:102
Block #7543 Timestamp:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:06:17 IST Value:102
Block #7542 Timestamp:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:06:14 IST Value:102
```

what am I doing wrong? appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 things:

- to get the other values, you need to look at another index in memory. Like so `web3.eth.getStorageAt(mycontractaddress, 1, startBlock-i);` and `web3.eth.getStorageAt(mycontractaddress, 2, startBlock-i);`. If `1` and `2` don't work, the numbers are at another index.
- your `samplecont.setnumbers()` transactions were probably all mined in the same block. Try spacing your transactions [in consecutive blocks](https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6).

Comment: :) Perhaps mark as solved?

Comment: Just did Xavier, thanks! new to stack-exchange  :p